# Quiero saber como pasar un ciclo for de django dentro de javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

Este es mi código:

```
{%for obj in empaque %} 
        celdae = {{"obj.celda"}}
        {%enfor%}

        if (document.empaque.celda.value == celdae) {
            alert("La celda ya esta ocupada") document.empaque.celda.focus() return false;}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es recorrer el ciclo e ir comparando si la variable que digite en el formulario es igual a una que ya existe, y si es así, entonces que salga el mensaje y me permita cambiar el número de celda.

Answer (score 1):

Debes tomar ese objeto **empaque** en tu vista y traerlo al template como un array, no sé que es lo que tengas ahí, pero por si acaso te dejo esto: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

Una vez que **celdae** te pueda devolver un array, por ejemplo:

```
celdae = {{ empaque }}
```

te dará como resultado:

```
celdae = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8]
```

Una vez que lo tengas así, puedes comprobar si el valor ingresado existe en ese array de esta manera:

```
if (celdae.indexOf(document.empaque.celda.value) > -1) {
    alert("La celda ya esta ocupada");
    document.empaque.celda.focus();
    return false;
}
```